# What is the difference between DH and RA in Jeppesen charts?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, aeronautical-charts, iaps, jeppesen

In CAT II and CAT III Approach Charts, the Jeppesen version of charts depicts both the "DH" and the "RA".

And, I found out that they are somewhat different.

So, why do these differences occur?

Averagely about 2 ~ 3 ft deviations are existing.

Comment: Please edit and give some examples.

Answer (score 6):

This entry is defined in the [Jeppesen Charts Legend](https://ww2.jeppesen.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Introduction-to-Jeppesen-Navigation-Charts.pdf) as follows:

[image: Jeppesen Cat II minima]

The difference between radio altimeter (RA) and decision height (DH) is the different baseline. The radio altimeter will measure height above ground (directly below you) whereas the decision height uses the runway as a baseline. I made a sketch to illustrate the difference with the numbers of the example above:

[image: example sketch]

It is usually not an issue for CAT III because at a typical DH of 50' you are already above the runway threshold on a normal glideslope (and for no DH it obviously doesn't apply). For CAT II with a typical DH of 100' there could be sloping terrain in front of the runway, but typically not much, that is why you see only a few feet difference. If there is a steep slope or a ditch in front of the runway, radar reflectors can be used to imitate a flat surface as shown in [this related answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/90069/33692).

This example from Munich (EDDM) shows the RA entry only for the CAT II:

[image: EDDM ILS 08L]

Comment: Also, some CAT III approaches have no DH (just an RVR).

Comment: Just a reminder that RA could be considerably _larger_ than DH, should the ground _rise_ to meet the end of the runway. [Lukla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenzing-Hillary_Airport), I'm looking at you...

Comment: The **FAA** CAT III A,B,C definitions no longer apply and "*Operators will use the published minima in conjunction with their Operations Specifications to determine the lowest landing minima allowed to them, as is currently done.*" [see this reference](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2012/02/16/2012-3692/removal-of-category-iiia-iiib-and-iiic-definitions)

Comment: Thx for the detailed explanation!
I was able to totally understand what you wrote. Have a good day!

Comment: @757toga Got it, I removed all references to CAT IIIA or CAT IIIB (they were not relevant for the answer anyway). Jeppesen still prints separate IIIA and IIIB minima for other countries though (as shown in the Munich example).

Comment: @FreeMan I'm pretty sure Lukla does not have ILS and if they do, certainly not CAT II. The [linked answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/90069/33692) says that slope should be kept below 2% for 200m in front of the runway for CAT II ILS.